# Copying a range based on 3 separate values

Tags: excel, vba, header, range, row

I have 2 workbooks. One named in the format of YYYYW**.xlsx, where the *'s represent the week number, and one named similarly but with project control on the end. There are a number of rows in the first workbook that contain a number of values. They range from 300--- numbers to 800--- numbers. These also have a delivery date and whether the project is active or closed.

The project control workbook contains 3 sheets, one for 2012 projects, one for 2013 projects and one for closed.

What I want to ask is how to programatically get the ranges of data and transfer them to the corresponding sheets in the new workbook.

Thanks

```
Project|    Description             |   Delivery  |   Total Sales  |  
------------------------------------------------------------------------        
300661 |CCBS - HLP250               |   01/01/2012|  Active        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------      
300710 |STOCK - ITM250 ELECTRICS    |   01/01/2012|  Closed        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------      
300731 |Nirvana: 4th Piece packer   |   28/02/2012|  Closed        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
300766 |STOCK - SATU                |   01/01/2012|  Active        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
300767 |STOCK - HLP 250 CONVERSION  |   01/01/2012|  Active        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
300768 |STOCK - PNEUMATIC, EMBOSSING|   01/01/2012|  Active        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
412972 |I.T.M. BV                   |   23/05/2013|  Closed        |
------------------------------------------------------------------------      
412986 |I.T.M. BV                   |   17/07/2012|  Closed        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
413001 |I.T.M. BV                   |   06/08/2012|  Closed        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
510003 |Internal Project for issuing|   27/12/2013|  Active        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------    
600161 |Tabak Invest  Kit & Conv    |   28/02/2012|  Closed        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
600166 |UTC DUBAI                   |   10/01/2012|  Closed        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------     
600168 |UTC HLP250 Conversion       |   20/02/2012|  Closed        | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above information needs to be sorted by the delivery year, whether it is open or closed and once placed in the correct sheets it needs to be copied into numerical order as shown.

With the above example project 510003 would go into workbook 2013 because of the delivery date and the active status whereas 300661, 3006, 300767 and 300768 would all go into 2012 and the remaining would go into the closed sheet as the projects are complete and have closed status

Comment: This is relatively easy to do from the sounds of your question, but have you tried anything yourself? If so, please post the code you've tried and where it's not working for you. Then we can pitch in and get it working.

Comment: So I'm not overly sure how to select the range based on a value in a cell. The only thing that I did was ran a macro and selected the values but as expected the code just showed as the cells I had highlighted.selected as the range when this is something I need to be automated without user input

Comment: please see edited question for example of data to be moved

Comment: Why would you need to sort it according to year? Create a macro that runs through the range and checks whether the delivery year is 2012 or 2013, depending on that you'll have two to add it to the correct workbook. Once you've looped through the range set a filter in each workbook on the column containing the project id. You can easily solve this by recording a macro and building your code step by step and first start with a few rows and once finished expand the range.

Comment: When I say sort it I mean put the 2012 ones in sheet 2012 and 2013 into 2013, I shouldn't use actual terms to explain what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get very much started. You'll have to make some tweak to match your actual data and files, but the structure should be solid.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveIt()

Dim wkbData As Workbook, wkbPaste As Workbook

Set wkbData = ThisWorkbook
Set wkbPaste = Workbooks("ProjectControl")

With wkbData

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Sheets(1) 'assumes data is in sheet1

    With wks

        ' -> note that use of .usedrange implies data is in a table with no other _
            data or formatting in the worksheet
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 4, "Closed"

        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        rng.Copy wkbPaste.Sheets("Closed")

        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 4, "Active"
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 3, xlFilterThisYear

        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        rng.Copy wkbPaste.Sheets("2012").Range("A1")

        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 4, "Active"
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter 3, xlFilterNextYear

        Set rng = Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        rng.Copy wkbPaste.Sheets("2013").Range("A1")

    End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is amazing, several small (i hope) issues. I didn't explain correctly and the filter of xlthisyear and xlnextyear are going to fail because there are full dates in the delivery date column, lik 03-02-2012, also there is some data in the rows that have to go into certain cells, how simple is that to achieve/how to amend your code for this?

Comment: did you try the filters of `xlThisYear` and `xlNextYear` before saying they didn't work? If not, please test the code, you may find that it does indeed work (if you are on xl2007/2010). If not, that's a different issue. :( In terms of getting data into specific cells, since this is a separate question that what you originally asked, please accept this answer and post another question on SO so you can get the help you need with that. It will go a long way, if you show the efforts you made to solve the problem, as well.

Comment: Yeah I tried the filters, they filter the columns but once the filter is applied it doesn't have any data, I stepped through the code and it applies the filter correctly but it doesn't recognise the date values and as such once filtered there is no data to copy and the program stops

Comment: @JamesDev -> that is because the date values are in European format. If you convert them to US format, it should work.

Comment: OK so to make it a bit easier for the filter I entered the following code 

    Range("C9:C128").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "yyyy"
This formats half of the dates correctly and takes that information, but any of the dates shown as dd-mm-yy don't convert, is there a way to change the 12's to 2012's?, I attempted a find and replace but forgot about all the money data and that got changed

Comment: That was because I selected all like an idiot, have done it with the selected range but still having trouble, will accept your answer as your suggestion does what I asked for. It is my data that is being a bit uncooperative

Comment: @JamesDev pesky data ...  but if the data was always smooth, we wouldn't have jobs :)

Comment: True Story, still struggling with this slightly but I think it's just a case of tinkering with the data until it works